# Is $\lim\limits(\prod_{i\leq n} K)\cong\cup_i(\prod_{j\leq i}K)$ true?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, category-theory

Consider a family of $K-$vector spaces $\prod_{i\leq n}K\to\prod_{i\leq n+1}K$ by embedding where embedding is done by identifying the basis $(1,0,\dots,0)\to (1,0,\dots,0,0),...$ and similarly for the rest.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Is $\lim\limits_n(\prod_{i\leq n} K)\cong\cup_i(\prod_{j\leq i}K)$ true? Should I conclude $\cup_i(\prod_{j\leq i}K)=\prod_N K$?

Note that   LHS means $\prod_{j\in N}K$ whereas every element of RHS arises from a finite sequence. Do I even have an infinite non-trivial sequence in RHS but it seems that all my sequence on RHS must terminate at finite position? However, I can identify the limit in set theoretical sense and then use $lim_n(\prod_{i\leq n}K)=\sqcup_{n\in N}(\prod_{i\leq n}K)/\sim$ where $\sim$ identifies element by the canonical embedding. What is wrong with my thought process?

Comment: Sorry if the question is too obvious, but aren't your spaces all $\mathbb{k}^n$ with the inclusions $ p \in \mathbb{k}^n \hookrightarrow (p,0) \in \mathbb{k}^{n+1}$? I'm having a hard time following the notation.

Comment: @GuidoA. There is difference between $\oplus_n K$ and $\prod_n K$ as one is direct limit and the other one is inverse limit. This is more or less saying direct and inverse limit not commuting for $k-$vector spaces.

Comment: Yeah, but it coincides with my description, no? In each step, you only take the product a finite amount of times and finite coproducts coincide with finite products in $\mathsf{Vect}_{\mathbb{k}}$ (or any abelian category iirc).

Comment: @GuidoA. Yes. That is correct.

Comment: I'm not claiming this holds for infinite families, I wanted to be sure that you are taking the (co) limits of just $\mathbb{k}^n$ and not some other object. Follow up question, is the LHS are you taking the limit or the colimit over the diagram of inclusions?

Comment: @GuidoA. The LHS is taken by the limit via the morphism $p\in k^n\to (p,0)\in k^{n+1}$ as you have described. I want to say $\cup_{i\in N}(\prod_{j\leq i}K)=\prod_N K$. I doubt this part is wrong as $\prod_N K$ contains infinite sequence but it must belong to $\cup_{i\leq N}(\prod_{j\leq i}K$ for some $i$ which is not possible.

Comment: I have to go now, but I will add an answer later. Here's a hint: the product satisfies a very specific universal property. Also, to make sense of the diagram of inclusions you described, one should take a colimit, because limits of diagrams with initial objets are just the functor evaluated in the initial object (see for example Exercise 3.1.ix. of Riehl's Category Theory In Context) which in this case would be $\mathbb{k} \neq \mathbb{k}^\mathbb{N}$. Even then, the colimit of that diagram is the set theoretic union you describe in the RHS but is not equal to the product.

Comment: @GuidoA. Then the question is very basic. I should have interpreted the infinite union as a colimit procedure rather than naively substitute the limit. There should be some requirements for substitution procedure as in continuity.

Comment: I don't know if this answers your question but if you have a diagram of vector spaces $V_i$ included in the next, it has limit $V_1$ and colimit $\bigcup_i V_i$. What do you mean by 'substitution procedure'?

Comment: @GuidoA. Canonically $V_i$ is embedded in $V_{i+1}$. So $\cup_{i\in N}V_i=V_\infty$ where $V_\infty$ is the largest target space where all $V_i$ being embedded.

Comment: @GuidoA. Here I am treating this as a functor $\cup_{i\leq -}V_i: N\to Vec_K$ where $V_i$ are vector spaces arranged in such a way to allow identification $V_i\subset V_{i+1}$.

Comment: @GuidoA. I see what is wrong with my though process. The point is $\cup_{i\in N} V_i\neq "V_{\infty}"=\prod_NK$.

Comment: Okay, that works and indeed gives the union! But as we said it's a colimit rather than a limit because the arrows point from each $V_i$ towards $V_\infty$ (at least in an intuitive sense).

Comment: To be clearer, the only misconception here was to interpret the colimit as a product (sorry, this should be a chat but I'm on mobile).

Comment: @GuidoA. I normally do not use colmit or limit. I always use direct limit=colimit and inverse limit=limit.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is intended to sum up the discussion in the comments. With the intention of clearing up some misconceptions, a slightly more categorical analysis is given before arriving at the concrete example of the post.

Take $(V_i)_{i \geq 1}$ a sequence of vector spaces with $V_i \subset V_{i+1}$. This gives a diagram

$$
V_1 \subset V_2 \subset \dots V_n \subset \dots  \tag{$\star$}
$$

over the category $\omega = 1 \to 2 \to 3 \to \dots$ which can be thought of $\mathbb{N}$ as a poset: we have an arrow $n \to m$ iff $n \leq m$. Concretely, the diagram $(\star)$ is given by mapping $i$ to $Fi = V_i$ for each $i \geq 1$ and $n \to m$ which is $n \to n+1 \to \dots \to m$ as the composition of inclusions from each $V_i$ to the next, from $n$ to $m$. Now, having constructed a diagram, one may wonder whether $\lim F$ and $\operatorname{colim} F$ exist, and how they can be described.

Note that in the category $\omega$, we have an initial object (namely $1$). Is is an instructive exercise to prove that if a category $J$ has an initial object $i$ and $F : J \to \mathcal{C}$ is a diagram, then $\lim J = Fi$. Hence, for $(\star)$ we get

$$
\lim J = F(1) = V_1.
$$

As for the colimit of $(\star)$, I claim we have $\operatorname{colim} F \simeq \bigcup_{i \geq 1}V_i$. It suffices to see that the latter verifies the universal property of the colimit: we have inclusion maps $j_r : V_r \to \bigcup_{i \geq 1}V_i$ for each $s$ which commute with the inclusions $V_i \subset  \dots \subset V_{j}$. It suffices to check that they commute for $V_i \subset V_{i+1}$ (why?). Noting the inclusions $ s_k : V_k \hookrightarrow V_{k+1}$ we get that $j_{k+1}s_k(v) = j_{k}(v)$ for each $v \in V_k$. This is because the first expression is looking at $v$ as an element of $V_{k+1}$, and then embedding it in the union, and the latter is directly looking at $v$ as a vector on the union. Hence we have built a cone $(j_r : V_r \to \bigcup_{i \geq 1} V_i)_{r \geq 1}$ under $F$. Finally, let's prove that it is universal in this sense: if we have another cone $(\mu_r  : V_r \to W)_{r \geq 1}$, then the function

$$
\mu : v \in V_r \subset \bigcup_{i \geq 1}V_i \longmapsto \mu_r(v) \in W
$$

is well defined, linear and the only one such that the new cone factorizes via the original inclusions, i.e. $\mu$ is the only linear function such that $\mu j_r = \mu_r$. This completes the proof of $\operatorname{colim} F \simeq \bigcup_{i \geq 1} V_i$.

Now, going back to the original question: here $V_i = \mathbb{k}^i$ and so $\lim F  = \varinjlim V_i = \mathbb{k}$ and $\operatorname{colim} F = \varprojlim V_i = \bigcup_{i \geq 1} \mathbb{k}^i$. Hence if we interpret the limit as an inverse limit (i.e. a colimit) the statement is true. What is false is that $\bigcup_{i \geq 1} \mathbb{k}^i \simeq \mathbb{k}^{\mathbb{N}}$. The former has countable dimension, a basis given by $e_i = (0, \dots, 0, \overbrace{1}^i,0,\dots)$, but the latter does not.

Comment: Why it is obvious that $\prod_N K$ has infinite dimension? I expect it has at least dimension $2^N$ or power set of $N$ given binary basis showing up.

Comment: Well, for one $2^\mathbb{N}$ has the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$. But with less work, note that the sequences $e_i = \delta_{ij}$ are infinite and linearly independent.

Comment: Note that I actually claim that $\dim \mathbb{k}^\mathbb{N} > \aleph_0$. That (to me at least) is less obvious. You can however find proofs of it on this site.